# 3D Mesh reconstruction triangulating input points only

Tags: 3d, cgal, triangulation

I am currently trying to solve the following problem, I have a set of points, which are the base point of some guide hair, I want to be able to triangulate those points so I can generate barycentric coordinates out of those points. I tried with delaunay triangulation using matlab, the only way I could make it to work was by doing the triangulation on a 2d plane like xz, but that is too much of a constraint for what I have in mind, here my test case:

Here is my starting data set, the points i wish to triangulate are the 3d points at the base of the curves:
[image]

Here the result of the triangulation on the 2D plane XZ which gives a decent result:
[image]

Unluckily this is way too much of a semplification, due to the fact that I might have to triangulate points sampled from a dog, cat ,monster mesh, where a 2D triangulation doesnt really fit. If I try to triangulate in 3D i get the following result:
[image]

As you can see there are triangles going in every direction not a consistant surface.

Now, by googling around i found that my problem is more of a surface reconstruction and CGAL can actually help with it, so I did my homework and found this:
http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/index.html#title7

Which looks like exactly what I need, but the down side is that the limit surface is generated then tassellated, it does not triangulate the given input points, but the tassellation can actually be controlled with a distance parameter.
Is there a way to constraint the tassellation using the given input point?
I am also looking at other possibilities using other freamworks but if possible I would like to stick with cgal. 
Thank you for your time.
M

Comment: If you are looking for a surface going through your input points, you should look at the [Advancing Front Reconstruction Package](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction).

Comment: You can consider [BallPivoting](http://www.research.ibm.com/vistechnology/pdf/bpa_tvcg.pdf) but it works only for dense point clouds. Your dataset is too coarse.

Comment: @sloriot thank you I will look into that.

Comment: @Alberto, interesting, well i guess i can easily generate extra points for the tassellation, then try to simplyfiy it by keeping the original points? means do not collapse/kill a triangle if involves an original point?